# Bundle JS files with webpack scripts?

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, bundle, npm-scripts

I'm super new to webpack and I do not seem to find a way to bundle JS files as I did with Gulp in a very easy way. I've been searching a bit but didn't find any straight answer to it.

Right now I'm creating two minified files by using in my `package.json` file, but I would love to have a single one instead:

```
"scripts": {
    "stand-alone": "concurrently 'webpack --config=webpack.config.js src/whatever.vue demos/build.min.js --output-library=whatever1'  'webpack --config=webpack.config.js src/whatever2.js demos/mixin.min.js --output-library=whatever2'",
},
```

Then my `webpack.config.js` looks like this:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.js'
    }
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: {
          loaders: {
            scss: 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader',
            js: 'babel-loader'
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress: {
        warnings: false,
        drop_console: false,
      }
    })
  ],
};
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe you are looking for [entry points](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/).

In your `webpack.config.js` module exports object:

Define the `entry` property:

```
 entry: {
    app: ['./path/to/file.js', './path/to/file2.js'],
  },
```

Define the [`output`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/) property:

```
 output: {
   path: '/path/to/assets', // ex. '../../wwwroot/dist'
   filename: '[name].js', // Substitutes [name] with the entry name, results in app.js
   publicPath: '/'
 },
```

---

Change your script to:

```
"scripts": {
    "stand-alone": "webpack --config=webpack.config.js",
},
```

---

If you are using Vue + Webpack, I recommend that you take a look to [vue-cli](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli) and generate a project using the webpack template. It is more advanced, but you can see the documentation and get an idea of what you are missing.

Run the following:

```
npm install -g vue-cli // install vue cli globally

vue init webpack my-project // create a sample project
```

---

If you want to generate multiple output files, you can have more than one entry point like so:

```
  entry: {
    app: ['./path/to/file.js', './path/to/file2.js'],
    mixins: './path/to/mixins.js',
    vendors: ['./path/to/vendor.js', './path/to/vendor2.js']
  },
```

This will write to disk `./path/to/assets/app.js`, `./path/to/assets/mixins.js`, `/path/to/assets/vendors.js`.

Comment: If I want to keep both, the separate files, as I have now with the current script, and the bundle one, do I need to create a different webpack.config file for the bundle script?
Can't I just do it in the same one?

Comment: I updated the answer, so that you can see how to add multiple entry points, resulting in several output files. I hope that is what you are looking for.